# Plotting discrete sin wave through Latex

Tags: latex

I am trying to plot a sin wave : `3sin(100*pi*t)` through latex where t will be in millisecond. I want to draw the discrete signal which was sampled at `Fs = 300 samples/sec`.

I have tried this code:

```
\begin{figure}%Sampled sine squence
 \caption{Discrete Time Signal}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \begin{axis}[%
            standard,
            domain = 0:15,
            samples = 13,
            xlabel={$n$},
            ylabel={$x[n]$}]

            \addplot+[ycomb,black,thick] {3*sin(100*180*x/13)};

        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

\end{document}`

but I am getting a different result than the one I am expecting.

[image]

My result should be like plot-B here but I am getting plot-A. 
Any suggestion, how i should do that?

Comment: Can you tell us what you expected and what the results were? Did you try anything else? The more details you provide the more help we can be. Feel free to improve your question by editing it.

Comment: i have added a picture to show my result and expected result. thanks

Answer (score 1):

The code calls for a ycomb of 13 samples across the domain, which is exactly what you get with plot-A (exclusive of endpoints). I believe that you need

```
samples = 5,
```

to achieve the desired result.

Comment: actually, i was trying to see the effect of sampling on a sinusoid signal. i have plotted 3*sin(100*pi*t) which is continuous and then I want to sample it by using sampling freq = 300 samples/sec which will make it discrete. now i somehow got the result i wanted as it was in the book already. but i cant understand yet, how to change the for such case. i hope u have understood  my prob.

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid that I do not understand your issue, or at least I do not understand how a LaTeX figure of the sort you're looking at is applicable to understanding the effects of sampling on a signal.  Perhaps you should be studying [tag:signal-processing].  I'd browse a bit before posting a question.